# Janela Modal e Manipulação de Dados

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho a seguinte dúvida:

Estou trabalhando num projeto onde tenho um formulário de cadastro e preciso abrir uma janela modal para incluir um endereço em um formulário.

Exemplo:

No meu formulário tenho 3 tipos de Endereço.

Endereço Residencial > O usuário clica num botão que abre um modal (carrega outra pagina php) dentro do modal carrega o maps do google e um campo com o endereço, depois que o usuário especificar o endereço e clicar em inserir volta pro formulário com o endereço preenchido.

Eu já tenho a página `.php` (cad_novo.php) que consulta o google maps e autocompleta o endereço e guarda o endereço selecionado num campo.

Preciso saber como carregar um modal com essa minha pagina `.php` (cad_novo.php) e como passar os dados para o formulário e auto imputar no campo endereço para depois fazer o submit com o endereço que o cara selecionou através do google maps.

A ideia é que ele não altere o endereço e tenhamos sempre o endereço que vem do google

Pensei em fazer isso com javascript mas não sei se é possível manipular os dados dessa maneira.

Não entendo de Ajax, mas se for uma opção eu procuro aprender.

Atualmente o site esta sendo desenvolvido com cms joomla 3x.

Comment: veja minha resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/83066/vari%C3%A1vel-php-dentro-de-modal

Answer (score 0):

Existem varias formas de fazer isso... vou expor uma.

Vamos imaginar os botões (End.Residencial) e (End.Comercial)
O usuário da um clique em (End.Residencial) então abre um modal com um form dentro dele (FormResidencial) o usuário preenche e da um gravar.

Bom,... no gravar você pega as informações do form (FormResidencial) e grava no banco e dispara uma função com Jquery para armazenar os dados preenchidos no (FormResidencial) e da um show em uma div sua com esses campos e um replace dos inputs pelo valor preenchido anteriormente.

É uma solução, mas como disse existem varias e bem melhores que está.

Exemplo jQuery.... (o valor do input vem de um span escondido)
http://jsfiddle.net/fellipesousa/ZW5dC/

Comment: Até pode funcionar, mas o que eu preciso é tipo passar o valor da janela filho pra pai. Estou vendo agora se consigo utilizar um iframe pra fazer essa interação. Mesmo assim Agradeço a disposição em ajudar =)