# Recuperar dados na Modal em PHP

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho um botão que chama uma tela `modal`, passando o ID do registro em questão.
Gostaria de saber como recuperar os dados desse ID, no momento em que exibir o Modal, para que consiga trazer os dados na tela?

Modal:

```
echo '<td><a href="#modal-editar" style="margin-right: 1%" class="btn btn-info tip-top" data-toggle="modal" chamada="'.$r->idChamada.'" title="Editar Valores da Chamada"><i class="icon-pencil icon-white"></i></a></td>';
```

Modal Estrutura:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="modal-editar" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <form action="<?php echo base_url() ?>chamadas/adicional/editar" method="post" >
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h5 id="myModalLabel">Editar Chamada - Valores</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <input type="hidden" id="idChamada" name="idChamada" value="" />
    <table class="table table-bordered ">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right; width: 200px"><strong>CLIENTE</strong></td>
            <td>SAPORITI DO BRASIL LTDA</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right; width: 200px"><strong>DATA DA CHAMADA</strong></td>
            <td>10/01/2015</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right; width: 200px"><strong>FUNCIONÁRIO</strong></td>
            <td>JOÃO DA SILVA STATUS</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right; width: 200px"><strong>VALOR EMPRESA</strong></td>
            <td><input type="number" name="dataInicial" value="10.00" class="span3"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right; width: 200px"><strong>VALOR FUNCIONÁRIO</strong></td>
            <td><input type="number" name="dataInicial" value="5.00" class="span3"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancelar</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger">Editar Valores</button>
  </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on('click', 'a', function(event) {
        var chamada = $(this).attr('chamada');
        $('#idChamada').val(chamada);
    });
});
```

Comment: é um modal Bootstrap?

Comment: Sim, bootstrap.

Comment: Veja se esta minha resposta te ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/83066/vari%C3%A1vel-php-dentro-de-modal/83079#83079

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para você recuperar e exibir os dados neste modal você terá que usar JavaScript para fazer uma requisição e retornar estes dados.

Você pode usar o Jquery.load().

Exemplo

```
$('#modal-editar').load('chamada?id='+id);
```

Neste caso o seu modal ira receber o conteúdo da página chamada. Com o id por parâmetro, na página chamada você faz a query para retornar os dados da chamada.

Você ainda pode definir que a função Jquery.load() carregue apenas uma div da página.

Exemplo

```
$('#modal-editar').load('chamada?id='+id+' #data');
```

Também há a opção de fazer uma requisição e retornar um JSON com os dados.

Exemplo:

```
$.getJSON( "chamada?id="id, function( data ) {

});
```

Neste caso a sua página chamada deverá retornar os dados em JSON, e ai você distribui os dados para o seu modal.

Editado.

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', 'a', function(event) {
        var chamada = $(this).attr('chamada');

        $.getJSON( "chamada?id="chamada, function( data ) {
            $('#nome').text(data['nome']);
            ...
        });

    });
});
```

Espero ter ajudado! :)

Comment: Eu tenho um jQuery que buscaria estes dados, porém, vou colar aqui pra você... Modifiquei a resposta

Comment: Pelo que eu vi na so seu jQuery você está colocando o id da chamada no atributo value do seu input, certo? Você precisa usar o jQuery para buscar estes dados e depois colocar nos elementos que você precisa. Editei minha resposta com um exemplo